# Handling Parameter of Directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i am passing the parameter(id) to the directive as follows

```
<input type="text" ng-model="entry.sale_qty" required style="width: 200px" on-keyupfn="handleKeypress(id)" >
```

And i have the definition of the on-keyupfn directive is as follows

```
app.directive('onKeyupFn', function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        var keyupFn = scope.$eval(attrs.onKeyupFn);
        elm.bind('keyup', function(evt) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                keyupFn.call(scope, evt.which);
            });
        });
    };
});
```

And the mentioned function(handleKeypress) for directive is as this

```
$scope.handleKeypress = function(key) {
    $scope.keylog.push(key);
    if ($scope.keylog[len - 1] == 17 && $scope.keylog[len] == 13)
        $scope.addUser();
    len = $scope.keylog.length;
}
```

Now can anybody help me with the accessing of passed parameter(id) from html in the function "$scope.handleKeypress = function(key) {}"???

Comment: why not use `ng-keyup` directive?

Comment: the used directive is working properly for me , directive is not an issue the passed parameter is what i am not getting how to handle???

Comment: are you intend to push the key.which to `$scope.keylog` whenever key is pressed in input box?

Comment: and i don't think `keyupFn` is a function when after `scope.$eval`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `ng-keyup` here:

html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="entry.sale_qty" required style="width: 200px" ng-keyup="handleKeypress($event)" >
```

js:

```
app.directive('onKeyupFn', function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        scope.handleKeypress = function (e) {
            $scope.keylog.push(e.which);
            if ($scope.keylog[len - 1] == 17 && $scope.keylog[len] == 13) {
                $scope.addUser();
            }
            len = $scope.keylog.length;
        };
});
```